# Two keyboard handlers for a video game character

Tags: javascript, game, comparative-review, event-handling

The code below is equivalent. I can see pros and cons for both versions. Which is better: the short, clever way, or the long, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> way?

Short version:

```
character.on("key",function(key){
    var action = ({
            "a":{axis:"x",direction:-1},
            "d":{axis:"x",direction:1},
            "w":{axis:"y",direction:1},
            "s":{axis:"y",direction:-1}})[key[1]],
        stop = key[0]=="-";
    if (action)
        if (stop)
            this.walkdir[action.axis] = 0;
        else
            this.walkdir[action.axis] = this.lookdir[action.axis] = action.direction;
});
```

Long version:

```
character.on("key",function(key){
    switch (key){
        case "+a": 
            this.walkdir.x = -1;
            this.lookdir.x = -1;
        break;
        case "+d":
            this.walkdir.x = 1;
            this.lookdir.x = 1;
        break;
        case "+w":
            this.walkdir.y = 1;
            this.lookdir.y = 1;
        break;
        case "+s":
            this.walkdir.y = -1;
            this.lookdir.y = -1;
        break;
        case "-a": 
            if (this.walkdir.x == -1)
                this.walkdir.x = 0;
        break;
        case "-d":
            if (this.walkdir.x == 1)
                this.walkdir.x = 0;
        break;
        case "-w": 
            if (this.walkdir.y == 1)
                this.walkdir.y = 0;
        break;
        case "-s":
            if (this.walkdir.y == -1)
                this.walkdir.y = 0;
        break;
        case "space":
            this.setStance("jumping");
        break;
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't see how the long version is better.

Comment: It's faster and probably much easier to understand.

Comment: @Dokkat In the first example you shouldn't be defining a static object when the function is called - that's definitely going to become costly. Try benchmarking that by removing the object definition out of the function and just accessing it.

Comment: Faster? Probably not. Even if it were, I doubt it'd make any difference in real code. Easier to read? I think that's where we diverge :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine my point is not that it is easier to read. It's easier to understand, because it needs less knowledge in general (the first is full of JavaScript particularities).

Comment: @izuriel sure, but moving the object out the function would make it even more complicated for newcomers, as I'd have to introduce a closure.

Comment: @Dokkat These objections are pretty irrelevant: writing code for people who don’t understand the language is counter-productive since it prevents you from using its features properly. Never succumb to the temptation of doing that. In addition, this code only uses core language features, not obscure hacks.

Comment: I see. The remaining concern would be the speed. I think I have 3 choices: letting it as it is, and it creates a new object every function call (slow). Moving the object outside, and polluting the outer namespace. Wrapping it into a closure, and making the code possibly more complicated. Which one?

Comment: Wait, what? There seems to be some disagrement here, I'll benchmark it.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/object-inside-outside-function 
declaring the object inside looks slower, but I'd expect it to be MUCH slower. Weird.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short code wins hands down. I understood it *immediately*, and more importantly, I can trivially verify that the code is reasonably error free. This is *much* harder with the longer code.

You say that the longer code is easier to understand but I claim that this is *objectively wrong*.

Case in point, the long code uses lots of magic numbers: 1, 0, -1, … what do these stand for? Ah, the short code tells us: they are `direction`s.

The longer code also makes us scroll (depending on the screen size) to see the whole method. This *significantly* impacts ease of understanding. I believe there were even studies demonstrating this empirically (but I cannot cite them; *Code Complete* would probably be the relevant reference here).

The one thing I would change in the short code is the lookup itself: define the dictionary separately, maybe even outside the method, and perform the lookup as follows:

```
var action = movement_commands[key[1]];
```

And maybe think about tokenising `key` properly, i.e. assigning the parts to variables before using them. However, I think that the method is short enough to make this unnecessary.

You also said that the longer code is more efficient but I’d like to see a benchmark before I believe that. You probably think that the first code is slower because of the dictionary lookup. But consider that JavaScript is a dynamic language – every single variable access is potentially a dictionary lookup internally. So there is no difference in performance – indeed, the short code could be *faster* since there’s less variable lookup involved.

(Of course the two code snippets do different things: the long version handles jumping, and they behave differently when the character was previously walking in one direction and now you cancel walking into a different direction.)

Comment: I argue it's easier to understand, not read; mainly for a novice trying to grasp the code; but I'm not sure I should worry about that. About the speed, it's not because of the dictionary lookup, but because of it's creation, which makes it obviously much heavier. As you said, moving the object out of the function would solve the issue, but then, in order not to pollute the outer namespace, I'd have to introduce a closure, making it even worse for novices (and much less readable in general, IMO): http://jsfiddle.net/EXv7e/ . Note: I obviously prefer the smaller version. Great answer by the way.

Comment: @Dokkat Well you could declare `actions` outside of `on.character` entirely, as a global variable. I’m not a big fan of this, however (keep scope as small as possible).

Comment: @Dokkat A novice will only be a novice for a short time; once they encounter and learn how the short code works, they've learned something new that will help them from then on.

Comment: @Dokkat Also, the speed hit in creating a small, static dictionary like that is going to be completely unnoticeable given what the event is reacting to. (And probably unnoticeable in general compared to the function call itself; and it may just be JIT-compiled and only created once anyway...  (I'm not entirely sure if it would, though))